# Minimum of the intersection of two sets is equal to the greater of the minimums of these sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following theorem I cannot prove:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two such closed sets of numbers, that $A \cap B \not = \emptyset.$ Then
$$\min(A \cap B) = \max \{ \min(A), \min(B)\}.$$

I find it very easy to notice it, when I draw a number line and two intersecting closed intervals on it. I know that to show that $a = b,$ I can show that $a \leq b \wedge b \leq a$ or show that $a \not < b \wedge b \not < a.$ But still I am not able to prove it.

Can I ask somebody to give me a hint or show it to me? Thank you in advance. ;-)

Comment: Without loss of generality, assume $\min(A) \geq \min(B)$, so you are left to prove that $\min(A \cap B) = \min(A)$. Then apply the definition of $A \cap B$ and it should follow in a line or two

Comment: Are you assuming that A and B are closed bounded intervals?

Comment: Not necessarily intervals. Finite sets are fine too. :-) But bounded - yes. I always forget, that sets such as $[0, 1)$ are closed. Thank you Nitin.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=[0,2]\cup[4,6]$ and $B=[-3,-1]\cup[1,3]$.

Then $A\cap B=[1,2]$;  so $\min(A\cap B)=1$ but $\max\{\min A, \min B\}=0$

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out user84413. So I gess it works only for closed bounded intervals, exactly as you suggested.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what the problem is supposed to be about.